# Why use double instead of integer?

Tags: java, rounding

First things first: I come from php and want to widen my horizon with java! 
So I read some books. I saw that rounding a number is posible wit Math.round().

My question is as follows:
If I want to round a number as a decimal, I have to use this code:

```
double number;
number = 1.111222;
number = Math.round(number*100.0) / 100.0;
```

or
    `number = (digit) Math.round(number*100) / 100;`

But **why** does

```
number = Math.round(number*100) / 100;
```

doesn't do the exact same thing???

Thx in advance,

Marc

Comment: why is there a comma in the number 1,111222?

Comment: The `,` will not compile. Also I am not sure what you really mean because both `number = Math.round(number*100.0) / 100.0` and `number = Math.round(number*100) / 100;` do the same thing. Finally, what is `digit`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger They don't, dividing my `100` vs `100.0` at the and will produce a long in one case and a double the another.

Comment: @chancea Did you run the code?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I am considering `,` as a decimal. (which i realize now may be a wrong assumption)

Comment: https://ideone.com/iof7sl

Comment: @chancea I am assuming `comma` as a `comma`. This question should therefore be closed since 1. The code does not compile. 2. It's ambiguous.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Well the OP is from germany.  And they use a `,` for their decimals so it may just have been a mistake in the `OP`s question

Comment: Wow, the comma is because (I believe it's so called locale) and I'm from Germany. Also it is possible that I mistake a comma with a dot. Sorry for that!!! But the question remains! So consider "," as ".".

Comment: @chancea I don't think that should be an excuse for posting an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. We have dyslexic people on stackoverflow who don't give excuses for the record. Also, what's `digit`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I guess I see it more often since I primarily deal with [tag:excel] which people change up the decimal, list separator, etc _all the time_ so it doesn't bother me as much.  I just naturally change things as I copy the code over from questions to my own locale

Comment: @maen see my answer then :) and you may wish to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30531824/edit) your question and change that comma to a decimal

Comment: @chancea I would have never taken the efforts to see where the OP was from and didn't know that `,` is a decimal point in `Germany` as well. Kudos to you for the perseverance (I am not being sarcastic)

Answer (score 3):

If assuming that you mean to put a decimal point for that comma `1.111222`

The problem is that `100` will cast the value to a `long` while `100.0` will cast it to a `double`.  `long`'s cannot have decimals but `double`'s can.

Look at both cases:

Case 1 produces a `double`:

```
Math.round(1.111222*100.0) => Math.round(111.222) => 111
111/100.0 => 1.11
```

Case 2 produces a <strike>`int`</strike> `long`:

(I orignally thought `int` but was proven wrong by the output, the reason being `Math.round(double)` returns a `long` found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)))

```
Math.round(1.111222*100) => Math.round(111) => 111
111/100 => 1 //truncated due to being a long
```

You can see this by running this code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    double number = 1.111222;

    System.out.println(Math.round(number*100.0)/100.0);
    System.out.println(Math.round(number*100)/100);

    Object a = Math.round(number*100.0)/100.0;
    Object b = Math.round(number*100)/100;

    System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(b.getClass().getName());

}
```

Which prints:

```
1.11
1
java.lang.Double
java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Math.round` returns a `long`.
So the result of rounding (of type `long`) is divided by an `int`. Before division JVM converts both to `long`.
See here for Java [widening conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

It's clear in javadoc.

```
 Returns the closest {@code int} to the argument, with ties rounding up.
```

So `round(float)` returns `int`, and `round(double)` returns `long`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Math.round(), the result is an integer value. When you divide two integers (e.g. / 100), Java will perform an integer division, throwing away the fractional part of the result.

When you divide an integer by a double (e.g. / 100.0), Java will first convert the integer to a double value, and then perform a floating point division, retaining the fractional part.

Comment: Keep cool! I admit I mistake the comma with a dot. I'm from Germany and these are my first steps in java. Since yesterday. O.K. this was wrong, but the question and the answer was what I've been looking for. So thank you Alan!